# OpenGL not rendering to correct target

Tags: opengl, textures, fragment-shader, fbo

I have a fbo, with 8 textures in it (g-buffer). What I'm trying to do, is to render all information from opaque objects to first four(color, normal, position, depth), and info from transparent objects to the last four textures. However, openGL seems to only want to render to firs four, no matter what I do. Also, the first frame when the application starts, is form some wierd reason the texture I use for my transparent objects.

Shader that writes to g-buffer:

```
in vec2 texcoord;
in vec3 worldpos;
in mat3 tbnmatrix;

uniform sampler2d diffuse;
uniform sampler2d normalmap;
uniform sampler2d dispmap;

uniform float dispmapbias;
uniform float dispmapscale;

uniform float specularintensity;
uniform float specularpower;

uniform float opacity;

uniform vec3 c_eyepos;

layout (location = 0) out vec4 diffuseColor;
layout (location = 1) out vec4 normalColor;
layout (location = 2) out vec4 positionColor;
layout (location = 3) out float depthcolor;
layout (location = 4) out vec4 diffuseColorT;
layout (location = 5) out vec4 normalColorT;
layout (location = 6) out vec4 positionColorT;
layout (location = 7) out float depthColorT;

void main(){
```

//Just calculating displaced texture coordinates
    vec2 texcoords = calcParallaxTexcoords(dispmap, tbnmatrix, normalize(c_eyepos - worldpos),         texcoord, dispmapscale, dispmapbias);

```
//Calculating normals
vec3 n = normalize(tbnmatrix * (255.0/128.0 * texture(normalmap, texcoords).xyz - 1)); 


if(opacity == 1){


diffuseColor = vec4(texture(diffuse, texcoords).xyz, 1);
normalColor = vec4(n, specularintensity);

positionColor = vec4(worldpos, specularpower);
depthColor = gl_FragCoord.z;

}

else{
    diffuseColorT = vec4(texture(diffuse, texcoords).xyz, opacity);
    normalColorT = vec4(n, specularintensity);
    positionColorT = vec4(worldpos, specularpower);
    depthColorT = gl_FragCoord.z;
}




}
```

I would post the code that creates my FBO, but it would be very much code, and hard to understand(because my architecture). Here are the values that I am passing in:

```
//Filters to be used in rendertargets
    GLenum filters[8] = { GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR,
 GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR, 
GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR };

//What I pass in to the third parameter of glTexImage2D
        GLenum internalFormats[8] = { GL_RGBA, GL_RGBA16F, GL_RGBA16F, GL_R32F, GL_RGBA, GL_RGBA16F, GL_RGBA16F, GL_R32F };

//Formats, not really important here
        GLenum formats[8] = { GL_RGBA, GL_RGBA, GL_RGBA, GL_RGBA, GL_RGBA, GL_RGBA, GL_RGBA, GL_RGBA };

    //Attachment to be used in glFramebufferTexture2D (and glDrawBuffers)
            GLenum attachments[8] = { GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, 
GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT2, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT3, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT4, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT5, 
GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT6, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT7 };
```

Comment: Have you checked `GL_MAX_COLOR_ATTACHMENTS`?

Comment: Are you calling `glCheckFramebufferStatus​()` anywhere? Perhaps, is it returning `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_UNSUPPORTED`?  As I understand it, it's fairly rare for implementations to support more than 4 color attachments, and they often have to have the same pixel formats.

Comment: Well, I am calling that and it is returning GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE. If it really is that rare to support that though, maybe I'm just better off with splitting that into 2 4-texture fbo's

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like it makes an invalid assumption about how fragment shader outputs work. It seems to assume that if no value is written to an `out` variable, the value in the corresponding render buffer will remain unchanged. That is not how it works.

If you do not assign a value to a `out` variable in the fragment shader, this means that it has an undefined value when the shader finishes. This undefined value will then be written to the render target.

The only way to not write a value to the render targets is to use `discard` in the fragment shader. But this discards the entire fragment. I'm not aware of a way to dynamically discard the fragment for specific render targets.

The best solution that comes to mind for only changing selected render targets, determined at shader run time, is to enable blending. Using a standard blend equation:

```
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
```

you can keep selected render targets unmodified by setting the alpha component of the corresponding output to zero. In your shader (shown only for the diffuse output):

```
if (opacity == 1.0) {
    diffuseColor = vec4(texture(diffuse, texcoords).xyz, 1.0);
    diffuseColorT = vec4(0.0);
} else {
    diffuseColor = vec4(0.0);
    diffuseColorT = vec4(texture(diffuse, texcoords).xyz, opacity);
}
```

An alternate approach is of course that you use two render passes, where you render the opaque objects in one pass, and the transparent objects in a second pass, each with only the corresponding 4 render targets.

Generally, you'll also need to make sure that you're not using more than `GL_MAX_COLOR_ATTACHMENTS` render targets. But this is guaranteed to be at least 8 in OpenGL 3.x, so this is not a problem in your case.